# How to add variable into the string in solidity?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, string

I want to add the extractedStr variable into the path?

```
bytes memory extractedStr;
string memory combine = '<path d="string(extractedStr)" fill="#FFFFFF"/>';
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is basically a string concatenation problem.

Since Solidity `v0.8.12`, you concatenate strings easily using:

```
string.concat(s1, s2)
```

You can check [solidity docs on strings and bytes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/types.html#bytes-and-string-as-arrays) for documentation reference.

In your case, this should help you concatenate your strings:

```
string public s1 = "string(";
string public s2 = ")";
bytes public yourBytes = '0x100';
string public combined;

function combine() public {
    combined = string.concat(s1, string(extractedStr), s2);
}
```

The combined string variable will now return:

```
'string(0x100)'
```

Answer (score 0):

version  0.8.12 or higher

```
    function concatA() external pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory extractedStr = '0xFFFF00';
        return string.concat('<path d="', string(extractedStr) ,'" fill="#FFFFFF"/>');
    }
```

result
0:string: `<path d="0xFFFF00" fill="#FFFFFF"/>`

otherwise for earlier versions

```
    function concatB() external pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory extractedStr = '0xFFFF00';
        return string(abi.encodePacked('<path d="', string(extractedStr) ,'" fill="#FFFFFF"/>'));
    }
```

result 0: string: `<path d="0xFFFF00" fill="#FFFFFF"/>`